# Find Calling Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

The stored procedure dbo.csp_Mapping_Step_003 is called by [dbo].[csp_Mapping] using the following statement:

```
exec csp_Mapping_Step_003 WITH RECOMPILE
```

When I try to use the following call to determine the calling proc programmatically...

```
DECLARE @fullyQualifiedObjectname sysname = 'dbo.csp_Mapping_Step_003'

SELECT
    referencing_schema_name  AS ObjectSchema
    ,referencing_entity_name AS ObjectName
FROM
    sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities (@fullyQualifiedObjectname
                                     ,'OBJECT');
```

..no rows are returned.

I know that SQL Dependencies are not perfect, but is there a more reliable way to get this information or is the "WITH RECOMPILE" option effecting the meta data? is there wat to get sQL Server to reanalyze the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

change exec csp_Mapping_Step_003 WITH RECOMPILE to

exec dbo.csp_Mapping_Step_003 WITH RECOMPILE

i think 'dbo' in @fullyQualifiedObjectname  is throwing it off.